# Mysql if condtion in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 3 tables news_feed,user_details and feed_comments from which i am fetching different type of feeds to show on users time line. Among these feeds types i have one feed type equivalent to numeric 9 which should only be fetched for the logged in user (lets take logged in user id = 55)

```
SELECT 
    `feed`.`id` as feedId,
    `feed`.`event_id` as eventId,
    `feed`.`type` as feedType,
    `feed`.`relation_id` as feedRelation,
    `feed`.`date_created` as dateTime,
    `user`.`id` as userId,
    `user`.`name`
FROM
    (`news_feed` AS feed)
        JOIN
    `user_details` AS user ON `user`.`id` = `feed`.`user_id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `feed_comments` AS fcomment ON `fcomment`.`feed_id` = `feed`.`id`
WHERE
    `feed`.`user_id` IN ('39', '14', '56', '15', '7', '54','55')
GROUP BY `feed`.`id`
ORDER BY `feed`.`ids` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

When i run this query it shows all feed types of all users but i only want to fetch feed type 9 only for logged in user among others feeds.[image]

Comment: write one query for loggedin user and another for not logged in user

Comment: So there is always a logged in user?

Comment: yes there is always a user logged in @SamiKuhmonen